# How to add dynamically attribute value using Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have logic where i am trying to add host url dynamically so it work in all env based on hosst, so below trying to find a file that is there in host but its never going into `$.each` statement , if call url directly `http://18.35.168.87:6000/Sdk/wrapper-sdk/client/out.json` it worked and rendered data, any idea what could have wrong in below code to achieve this task ?

main.js

```
function myFunction(val) {
    var url = "../../wrapper-sdk/" + client + "/out.json";
        if (window.location.hostname.indexOf("localhost") !== -1 ||
            window.location.host.indexOf("localhost") !== -1) {
            var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
            var host = '';
            $.each(scripts, function (idx, item) {
                if (item.src.indexOf('Sdk/wrapper-sdk') !== -1 && (item.src.indexOf('out.json') !== -1)) {
                    host = item.src.split('?')[0];
                    host = host.replace('wrapper-sdk/' + client + '/out.json', '');
                }
            });

   url = url.replace('../../', host);
        }
        $.ajax({
            url: url + "?no_cache=" + new Date().getTime(),
            dataType: "json",
            "async": false,
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function () {
                console.log('error while accessing api.json.')
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: If it's not reaching your `$.each()` this would suggest the condition has not been met. Any console errors?

Comment: @Twisty there is no error in console

Comment: I do not see where `client` is defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest breaking up some of your checks into their own function. Makes it just a bit easier to follow the logic.

```
function validIp(str) {
  var parts = str.split(".");
  var result = true;
  $.each(parts, function(i, p) {
    if (parseInt(p) > 0 && parseInt(p) < 255) {
      result = result && true;
    }
  });
  return result;
}

function checkLocalUrl(str) {
  var result = 0;
  if (str.indexOf("localhost") >= 0) {
    result = 1;
  }
  if (validIp(str)) {
    result = -1;
  }
  /*
  0 = Some Domain or Host Name, not LocalHost
  1 = LocalHost 
  -1 = IP Address
  */
  return result;
}

function changeSources(client) {
  if (checkLocalUrl(window.location.hostname) || checkLocalUrl(window.location.host) {
      var scripts = $("script");
      var host = '';
      scripts.each(function(i, el) {
        var src = $(el).attr("src");
        var nUrl = new URL(src);
        var pro = nUrl.protocol;
        var hn = nUrl.hostname;
        if (nUrl.pathname.indexOf('/Sdk/wrapper-sdk') == 0 && nUrl.pathname.indexOf('out.json') > 0) {
          host = pro + "://" + hn + "/wrapper-sdk/" + client + "/out.json";
        }
        $.ajax({
          url: host
          data: { no_cache: new Date().getTime() },
          dataType: "json",
          async: false,
          success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
          },
          error: function() {
            console.log('error while accessing api.json.')
          }
        });
      });
    }
  }
}
```

See also: [new URL()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL)

You can send a string to `checkLocalUrl()` and it will return `1` or `true` if it's potentially a localhost URL. It will return `0` or `false` if it's any other domain pattern or `-1` or `false` if it's an IP address.

In `changeSources()` we can use this to check for local urls and perform the AJAX you defined.

Comment: Perfect got it!